# Facebook Android SDK: Get user by app-scoped userId

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working with facebook android sdk and trying to implement the following scheme:

1. My android app asks user for access to his facebook account
2. I receive the user access token as a login result
3. I pass that token (which is a simple `String`) to my own backend server
4. On my server I need to find out who that user is and if there's an account on my backend server, that is connected to this user's facebook account, let the user login, otherwise show error message.

My problem is that from access token I can only retreive app-scoped `userId`, which can't be used by my backend to access the user information from facebook server. The code I use for handling login result is pretty simple:

```
facebookButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {
            //Pass token to my backend
            loginByToken(result?.accessToken?.token!!, FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)
        }

        override fun onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Facebook login cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException?) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

I'm also using the following autorization scheme:
 [image]

So, my question is how do I get the user data on my backend server? I guess it'd make sense if I also provide my app id for request user data, but I went through facebook documentation, and haven't found any way of doing so

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get data of the user is to use his access token. Since you pass that token to your server anyway, it should be no problem to use it:

```
/me?fields=id,name,...&access_token=xxx
```

For identifying returning users, you only need the app scoped id though. If you want to identify users across different Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/

Comment: But should I also pass my app id along with the access token? Because I just found out that in my case I should pass access token, app id and secret key (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/portability)

Comment: where do you want to pass it? in the api call, you only need to pass the token, and the fields you want to get. and appsecret_proof, if you want to be safe. NOT the app secret.

Comment: I'm not going to pass secret to my server, it supposed to know it already and later pass it to FB server, it's not necessary though and I'm not going to pass that anyway. The question is that I should probably pass APP_ID to FB which is not secret. Currently I pass only an access token, and when my backend tries to access user data, it says its not available because the user id is wrong

Comment: you should ONLY pass the token to your server. i thought that you mean passing stuff to the facebook api. you should definitely add appsecret_proof as well. i am not talking about the app secret. it is explained in the link you posted. about the app id: no, you don´t need that.

Comment: Ok, I guess passing token is enough, in fact it turned out that our backend team was able to retrieve user data just by an access token, BUT we need to match the users somehow, and we currently do that by matching userId from access token, and list of userIds that are kept at our server. If we find a pair, then we can let user to login to our server (not the facebook's). But since the token contains an app-scoped userId, we can't find a match

Comment: why can´t you find a match? what else did you store in your backend? what do you want to compare with? the app scoped id is the one unique way to identify users.

Comment: i have added a link for matching/identifying users across different apps, if that is the problem.

Comment: thanks for the reference, I guess I that's what I should use. We were trying to compare app-scoped ids with ids, that were used at the registration time (which could be both global and app-scoped)